# Importing OLAP metadata in SQL Server via linked server results in out-of-range date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, olap-cube, ssas-tabular

Currently, I am trying to extract metadata from an OLAP cube in SQL Server (via a linked server) using this simple query:

```
select *
into [dbo].[columns_metadata]
from openquery([LINKED_SERVER], '
    select *
    from $System.TMSCHEMA_COLUMNS
')
```

But in the result set, there is a column named RefreshedTime with values 31.12.1699 00:00:00.

Because of this value, the query gives this error message:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 9, Line 1 Error converting data type (null)
>   to datetime.

The problem is that I need to run the query **without** specifying the columns in the SELECT statement.

Do you know a trick to avoid this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you wanted not to have to mention the columns explicitly, but in case nobody can suggest a way to have it handle the 1699-12-31 dates, then you can fallback to this:

```
select *
into [dbo].[columns_metadata]
from openquery([LINKED_SERVER], '
SELECT [ID]
      ,[TableID]
      ,[ExplicitName]
      ,[InferredName]
      ,[ExplicitDataType]
      ,[InferredDataType]
      ,[DataCategory]
      ,[Description]
      ,[IsHidden]
      ,[State]
      ,[IsUnique]
      ,[IsKey]
      ,[IsNullable]
      ,[Alignment]
      ,[TableDetailPosition]
      ,[IsDefaultLabel]
      ,[IsDefaultImage]
      ,[SummarizeBy]
      ,[ColumnStorageID]
      ,[Type]
      ,[SourceColumn]
      ,[ColumnOriginID]
      ,[Expression]
      ,[FormatString]
      ,[IsAvailableInMDX]
      ,[SortByColumnID]
      ,[AttributeHierarchyID]
      ,[ModifiedTime]
      ,[StructureModifiedTime]
      ,CStr([RefreshedTime]) as [RefreshedTime]
      ,[SystemFlags]
      ,[KeepUniqueRows]
      ,[DisplayOrdinal]
      ,[ErrorMessage]
      ,[SourceProviderType]
      ,[DisplayFolder]
from $System.TMSCHEMA_COLUMNS
')
```

Comment: Okay thank you, but maybe do you know a way to change this system setting on the SSAS server ? Ex. 1699-12-31 to 1900-01-01

Comment: Or maybe do you know a query to retrieve the columns list of the DMV $System.TMSCHEMA_COLUMNS ?

Comment: Maybe do one select into where 1=0? Then you should have the column list and data types but no rows